# Releasing native pointers stored inside Java objects? Is there something analogous to C#'s IDisposable?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm writing Java code that calls C (using JNI) and holds a native pointer a class member as a `long`.

When I've done this in C#, the class that holds the native pointer should implement IDisposable.

Is there something similar that should be done in Java?

[This post](http://reedcopsey.com/2009/03/28/idisposable-part-1-releasing-unmanaged-resources/) by Reed Copsey explains why in C#:

> When we’re using native resources, there are two issues we need to
>   address using IDisposable.  The first relates to timing – if we’re
>   using a native resource, and we want to stop using it, we should have
>   a way to instantly stop using that resource.  The second relates to
>   safety – if we’re using a native resource, and are now done with it,
>   we need a way to make sure that resource is successfully cleaned. 
>   IDisposable can help with both of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` has a method [finalize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--), which is called by the garbage collector when an `Object` is disposed. Other than that, there's nothing standard in Java. The only other thing I can think of that might relate is Window.dispose, which releases system UI resources.